How to set a private Subscription variable to null (or undefined) from a unit test?
I'm currently writing unit tests for some older Angular code that I did not write and cannot change.
Here's a simplified example:
export class SomeServiceComponent implements OnDestroy {
 
  private someSubscription!: Subscription;
 
  constructor(public someService: SomeService) {
    this.someSubscription = this.someService.getSub$('data').subscribe(
      response => {
        ...
      }
    )
  }
 
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.someSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
 
 }
}

The code is working fine, and my unit tests can execute all code in the component, except for the one case where someSubscription is null (or undefined) when ngOnDestroy executes.
I can't explicitly set someSubscription to null or undefined from the unit tests - neither value is compatible - so is there another way to write a unit test that exercises the question-mark case in ngOnDestroy?

When writing test cases, we can just use any type to get rid of any type errors.
someSubscription: any = null;
// or
component['someSubscription'] = null as any;


We can use the below property access to set values for private variables!
desc("ngOnDestroy Tests", () => {
    it("should unsubscribe the subscription", () => {
        component['someSubscription'] = {
            unsubscribe: () => {},
        };
        spyOn<any>(component['someSubscription'], 'unsubscribe');
        component.ngOnDestroy();
        expect(component['someSubscription'].unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})

If you use the ?. typescript safe access, even if subscription is undefined or null you will not get any errors!
Typescript playground
TS
const someSubscription = null;

someSubscription?.unsubscribe();

const someSubscription2 = null;

someSubscription2?.unsubscribe();

JS
"use strict";
const someSubscription = null;
someSubscription === null || someSubscription === void 0 ? void 0 : someSubscription.unsubscribe();
const someSubscription2 = null;
someSubscription2 === null || someSubscription2 === void 0 ? void 0 : someSubscription2.unsubscribe();

Run in debugger, you will not get any errors!

Sorry, perhaps I am not being clear enough in the question - the problem is not verifying that unsubscribe gets called when someSubscriptionis defined. The problem is verifying thatngOnDestroydoes not error out whensomeSubscription` is not defined.

even if subscription is undefined or null you will not get any errors I know, but it's actually the code coverage of the ? case that I'm interested in. --- When I attempt to do const someSubscription: Subscription = null; I get Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'. and without the type I get Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'never'..

@500-InternalServerError just define someSubscription: any = null; to get rid of this error! You can just write component['someSubscription'] = null as any; Why dont you share the test case also!

That was the ticket! Put that in the answer, and I'll mark it as answered.
